# Secure connection to Windows

Tags: mount, windows

How do I create a secure connection with a mount point from Ubuntu 14.04 to a Windows 2012 file server? I need to be able to copy files from Ubuntu to Windows without being prompted for a password. The mount cannot use a Windows account with the password stored in plain text anywhere.

Comment: https scp ......

Comment: sorry, that's no help. Please expand your response.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer. Google search those 2 options,  see if they fit your needs, choose one, and ask a specific question  if you have a problem.